# ¿Por qué no se muestran los íconos de Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap

Estoy utilizando los íconos de bootstrap para agregar en un select (Igualmente no se muestran fuera), siguiendo la información que he leído, utilizo el CDN que se encuentra en la Web oficial

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">`

Para agregarlo en el HTML sigo este formato

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="">&#xF127; Ordenar</option>
    <option class="saa" value=""> &#xF5B0; A-Z</option>
    <option class="sad" value=""> &#x29E9; Z-A</option>
    <option class="spa" value=""> &#xf124; Precio</option>
    <option class="spd" value=""> &#xf062; Precio</option>
</select>
```

Pero no se muestran íconos, hay un código que si se muestra (Lo tomé de un ejemplo en una Web), sería este `&#x29E9;` no entiendo el porque

Comment: No sé en qué parte de la [documentación](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#usage) se indica que esa sea la forma de uso de Bootstrap Icons.

Comment: En la Web de `Bootstrap` en la sección `Íconos`

Comment: Al seleccionar un ícono en la parte inferior derecha tienes la opción que está en la imagen de la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Esto usa fuentes para simular iconos, empleaando caracteres poco comunes y en ellos asigna un icono. Esto `&#xf062` es básicamente una letra en formato Unicode, y lo que muestre en pantalla depende de la fuente.

Entonces al ser una fuente, hay que declarar el `font-family` respectivo a los elementos que tu deseas que usen aquella fuente. Como por ejemplo los elementos `select` y `option`

```css
select, option{
  font-family: "bootstrap-icons"
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="">&#xF127; Ordenar</option>
    <option class="saa" value=""> &#xF5B0; A-Z</option>
    <option class="sad" value=""> &#x29E9; Z-A</option>
    <option class="spa" value=""> &#xf124; Precio</option>
    <option class="spd" value=""> &#xf062; Precio</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo hice, al igual que ti, ahora solo me muestra solo el ícono al lado de la opción ordenar, los de abajo no exceptuando el de Z-A